# Why do I need to use org.apache.http.legacy when using Dagger2?

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2

We are upgrading a project from dagger 1.x to dagger 2.x. We converted everything to be compliant with dagger 2, but when we try to compile we get the following message:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import myapp.DaggerMyComponent;
             ^                   
  symbol:   class DaggerMyComponent        
  location: package myapp       

Note: Generating a MembersInjector for myapp.PageController. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
Note: Generating a MembersInjector for myapp.ScrollingItemPageController. Prefer to run the dagger processor over that class instead.
error: cannot access AbstractHttpEntity               
  class file for org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.      
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity not found\
```

adding `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` does resolve this issue, but I'd like to know what is using the `AbstractHttpEntity` and does including this library have any side effects?

edit:

Someone requested to see the networking dependencies. **Note that these dependencies were already in there before upgrading!**

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okhttpVersion}"
compile ("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okhttpVersion}")  {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
}

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
apt ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}")

compile ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}") {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
}

compile ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2'
}
```

Versions:

```
ext {
    supportVersion = '24.1.1'
    playServicesVersion = '9.4.0'
    butterknifeVersion = '8.2.1'
    daggerVersion = '2.6'
    retrofitVersion = '2.1.0'
    okhttpVersion = '3.4.1'
}
```

I do see other projects on github that use the same `useLibrary` but it is never explained why:

https://github.com/shohrabuddin/Dagger2-ButterKnife-Retrofit-OkHttp-Picasso-Gson_Annotations
https://github.com/frogermcs/GithubClient/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: We would have to know what uses networking in your code provided by dagger for this question to be answered

Comment: Why is that? We started getting this after upgrading dagger, not by adding OkHttp (which was already in there!)

Comment: I still think your issue is in **ScrollingItemPageController**

Comment: Why is that? It does absolutely nothing with http

Comment: The `ScrollingItemPageController ` has an `Inject` but its an abstract class, hence the warning

Comment: What is your Dagger2 version?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce added to question